# Make a route expire in a short time

Tags: node.js, django, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a task that for rating services. Users will be receiving a SMS text message including a short link. After click that short link, they will fill out the information and submit. And then I will store those information in the database.

That is the requirement, now move on to implement part. I am thinking to generate a route like this:

```
https://www.app.com/{customerId}/?access_token=fdsaf.dsaf.fdsafads
```

Then put it under `bitly` or `short.io`. The `access_token` will only valid for 10 seconds start from the time that the url is generated.

Do you think is it good enough for safety ? any suggestion would be highly appreciate.
Thank you.

// Edit the question

valid for 10 seconds right after user click the url or the token expired right after the user click (dont need the 10 seconds).

Comment: "Good enough for safety" is a big question that depends upon a lot of things.  10 seconds is a really short time for usability.  Some text messages won't even be received within 10 seconds.  What are the consequences of someone guessing the token and getting in?  How secure is the generation of the token?

Comment: @jfriend00 Is there any way i can count 10 seconds by the time user click the link ? or maybe the token expired right after the click it. I wont give them second chance. Thanks.

Comment: hm. then how i can use the token for user to submit the form so i can save in database ? i dont know. i need some suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: maybe instead of 10 seconds. i will set the token expired in 10 minutes. It would give user enough time to write a feedback.

Comment: also i think the access_token will need to be stored in database , right ? since this is a public url, so i dont want to using username or password to talk to back end and then the access_token need to update.

Comment: Sorry. I am kinda talking to myself above to find the solution. If you have any suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you generate a token (which must be done server-side), you would need to store it somewhere on the server and expire it automatically on the server so when a request URL comes back in containing a token, you can see if the token it contains is valid.  The token URL probably does not need the customerID.  If you want to know which customer a token is associated with, then just store that with the tokenID when you generate and store it originally.

Comment: From an end-user usability perspective, 10 minutes seems much more usable than 10 seconds.  That gives them a more reasonable time to receive the link, click the link and fill out the page.  The security of your token needs to come from how hard they are to guess and you should be able to make something that isn't guessable in 10 minutes just fine, but it will need to be a good, secure token.  It is a little odd that you're asking about security and not disclosing at all how you generate the token as that is a central aspect of it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What i really mean in the question is that how to design this in a way to make it secure.

Comment: @jfriend00 i dont think JWT token will fit in the url as `access_code` variable.

Comment: @jfriend00 ahhh. maybe i am overthinking. the token just need a random string( hard to guess) and store it in user table that associate with that user. I am getting there.

Comment: Yes, cryptographically random string is what you want here.

Comment: @jfriend00 i got the token setup in the server. I am currently implementing the expiration time for that token. i am going to add a column in database call: `expire_time` . What i am thinking now is that: if user click the link, the token valid, then `expire_time` will be update to `now() + 10 minutes` and then update new token. Not sure if its right way to go.

Comment: how can i set a timer in 10 minutes the token still good ?

Comment: This isn't the right way to be using Stackoverflow.  It isn't for an ongoing discussion about all the details of your implementation you run into.  You should be asking a single question and then people can supply an answer to that question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. I will post another question. Thanks again for all of your suggestion. That was super helpful.